# Utility of the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral

How does the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics as given by $\langle q_{f}|e^{-iHt/\hbar}|q_{i}\rangle = \int \mathcal{D}q(t)\ e^{iS[q]/\hbar}$ make manifest aspects of quantum mechanics such as symmetries?

Comment: This seems too broad. Have you read any book regarding this subject?

Comment: I need a short answer. I am not looking to read thousands and thousands of words from textbooks.

Comment: I don't think this has a short answer, hence my "too broad" comment. But maybe someone can give it a shot.